# Numpy: vectorized access of several columns at once?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, slice

I have scripts with multi-dimensional arrays and instead of for-loops I would like to use a vectorized implementation for my problems (which sometimes contain column operations).

Let's consider a simple example with matrix `arr`:

```
> arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

> arr
> ([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
    [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

> arr.shape
> (3, 4)
```

So we have a matrix `arr` with 3 rows and 4 columns.

The simplest case in my scripts is **adding** something to the values in the array. E.g. I'm doing this for single or multiple **rows**:

```
> someVector = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
> arr[0] += someVector

> arr
> array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7],    <--- successfully added someVector
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],         to one row
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

> arr[0:2] += someVector

> arr
> array([[ 2,  5,  8, 11],    <--- added someVector to two
         [ 5,  7,  9, 11],    <--- rows at once
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

This works well. However, sometimes I need to manipulate one or several **columns**. One column at a time works:

```
> arr[:, 0] += [1, 2, 3]

> array([[ 3,  5,  8, 11],
         [ 7,  7,  9, 11],
         [11,  9, 10, 11]])
           ^
           |___ added the values [1, 2, 3] successfully to
                this column
```

But I am struggling to think out why this **does not work** for **multiple columns at once**:

```
> arr[:, 0:2] += [1, 2, 3]

> ValueError
> Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-16-5feef53e53af> in <module>()
> ----> 1 arr[:, 0:2] += [1, 2, 3]

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast
>             together with shapes (3,2) (3,) (3,2)
```

Isn't this the very same way it works with **rows**? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add a 1D array to multiple columns you need to [*broadcast*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the values to a 2D array. Since broadcasting adds new axes on the left (of the shape) by default, broadcasting a row vector to multiple rows happens automatically:

```
arr[0:2] += someVector
```

`someVector` has shape `(N,)` and gets automatically broadcasted to shape `(1, N)`. If `arr[0:2]` has shape `(2, N)`, then the sum is performed element-wise as though both `arr[0:2]` and `someVector` were arrays of the same shape, `(2, N)`.

But to broadcast a column vector to multiple columns requires hinting NumPy that you want broadcasting to occur with the axis on the right. In fact, you have to add the new axis on the right explicitly by using `someVector[:, np.newaxis]` or equivalently `someVector[:, None]`:

```
In [41]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

In [42]: arr[:, 0:2] += np.array([1, 2, 3])[:, None]

In [43]: arr
Out[43]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  6,  7],
       [11, 12, 10, 11]])
```

`someVector` (e.g. `np.array([1, 2, 3])`) has shape `(N,)` and `someVector[:, None]` has shape `(N, 1)` so now broadcasting happens on the right. If `arr[:, 0:2]` has shape `(N, 2)`, then the sum is performed element-wise as though both `arr[:, 0:2]` and `someVector[:, None]` were arrays of the same shape, `(N, 2)`.

Answer (score 6):

Very clear explanation of @unutbu.

As a complement, transposition (`.T`) can often simplify the task, by working in the first dimension :

```
In [273]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

In [274]: arr.T[0:2] += [1, 2, 3]

In [275]: arr
Out[275]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  6,  7],
       [11, 12, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: Is transposition just a view on that array? So that this has about the same performance as the answer of @unutbu?

Comment: yes, it's a view. and roughly the same performance, even a bit faster ;) .